# Javascript always uses only first variable defined in if statement

Tags: javascript

I have spent several hours trying to understand whats going on but no success.
I use php values to define javascript variables.

So, `var sname` are the following:

```
var sname = 'Mónica'; //with an accented character
var sname = 'Edgar';
```

When I look at page source, everything is correct but alert always show the first sname - Mónica. When I put first Edgar, alert shows Edgar for both cases. If I replace accented name Mónica with some other name without accents, everything works correctly. No console errors, nothing. Does it mean that I can not use accented characters in javascript variables?

`var estilo` is always correct.

```
var fromname = 'edgar';
var username = 'monica';
var msg = 'eúíéñú';

if(fromname === username) {
    var estilo = 'me';
    var sname = '<?php echo $sender;?>';
} else {
    var estilo = 'you';
    var sname = '<?php echo $receiver;?>';
}

var htmlx='div class="bubble '+estilo+'"><p>'+sname+'</p><div">'+msg+'</div><p">'+hour+':'+minute+'</p></div>';


alert(htmlx);
```

Alert shows different `estilo` for each condition but always the the same `sname`.

Comment: Your PHP `echo` has a syntax error: `<?php echo ($receiver;?>` -- there's a left bracket but not a right one. Thus it will not output anything. Also, your `htmlx` appears to have a rather strange combination of quotes, which are also invalid (but not the cause of your problem).

Comment: without knowing how `fromname` and `username` are being set to it is a little hard to debug

Comment: I would argue that the PHP tag is *very* relevant to this question, despite it being removed.

Comment: @ObsidianAge That must be copying error or the script wouldn't run at all.

Comment: What do you see when you view the source code in the JavaScript debugger?

Comment: Post the actual HTML and script that the browser receives (as a [*minimal, reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: Obsidian Age, there is no syntax errors. I also tried to use json_encode() and thats why I forgot to remove 1 bracket. As I wrote, if I replace name Mónica with any other name without accent, the problem disappears.

Comment: There's no way that can affect how the `if` goes.

Comment: Paste the code from `View Source` when it doesn't work.

Comment: given the description of the problem, that can only mean that `$sender` and `$receiver` have the same value in PHP - as you haven't shown how these values are obtained, there is no other conclusion that can be made

Comment: as a general recommendation ... dont' declare `var`s inside code blocks if they will be used in an outer "block" - while this works in javascript and isn't going to be an issue in the code you've presented, just don't do it, declare the variables before the `if` statement in this case

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem:

```
if(fromname === username) {    
    sname = '<?php echo $sender;?>';
} else {
    sname = '<?php echo $receiver;?>';
}

var htmlx='div class="bubble '+estilo+'"><p>'+sname+'</p><div">'+msg+'</div><p">'+hour+':'+minute+'</p></div>';

delete sname;
```

Comment: It isn't clear how the code, that doesn't work, in your question, is different from the code, that does work, in your answer. If you want this question to be helpful for other users, maybe you can add an explanation, letting us know what didn't work before and how you fixed it.